# Unable to control volume using MediaElement.Volume property

Tags: c#, windows, audio, uwp, media

I'm trying to control the MediaElement volume level and increment it whenever I call the IncreaseVolume method. When it reaches the maximum volume I want to reset it back to the lowest volume setting. I'm noticing however that changing the volume property does nothing to the volume on playback when I call the TextToSpeech method, even though the MediaElement volume property does get set to the new value. What am I doing wrong here? Code is below:

```
    private static readonly MediaElement MediaElement = new MediaElement();
    private static readonly SpeechSynthesizer Synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();

    public static async void TextToSpeech(string text)
    {
        var stream = await Synthesizer.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(text);
        MediaElement.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
        MediaElement.Play();
    }

    public static void IncreaseVolume()
    {
        if (MediaElement.Volume >= 1)
        {
            TextToSpeech("Max volume reached");
            MediaElement.Volume = 0.1;
        }

        MediaElement.Volume += 0.1;
        TextToSpeech("New volume is " + MediaElement.Volume);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm noticing however that changing the volume property does nothing to the volume on playback when I call the TextToSpeech method

Please try to add the `MediaElement` to current page's Visual Tree, or in other words, you need to add the `MediaElement` as a child of the page. The **Volume** works only when the `MediaElement` is in the Visual Tree.

Need something like this:

```
  private static  MediaElement mediaElement = new MediaElement();
    private static  SpeechSynthesizer Synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        MyRootGrid.Children.Add(mediaElement);
    }
```